# Passing data from view to controller in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am working on a forgot password module in zend.I want 'memcode' of user to be send to the controller so that I can pass an query to reset password.

ForgotController.php

```
 public function changepasswordAction()
    {
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $dbAdapter=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $form = new ForgotForm($dbAdapter);
    $project = new Projects();
    $id=$this->params()->fromQuery('id');
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' =>$form));
    return $viewModel;

    }



      public function resetAction()
        {
        $pswd = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        $id=$this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);
        echo $id;
        $sql="UPDATE projects set password = '".$pswd."' where memcode = '".$id."'";
        $statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
        $result    = $statement->execute();
        }
```

view code:changepassword.phtml

```
echo $_GET['id'];
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,array('controller'=>'Forgot', 'action' =>'reset','id'=>$_GET['id'])));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);?>
<h4>Set new password</h4>
<p> Welcome! <?php //echo $this->user_email; ?> </p>
<table>
<tr>
<td><dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('password')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('password'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password'));
?></dd></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('confirm_password')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_password'));
?></dd></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><dt><?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
?></dd></td></tr>

</table>
</dd>
</section>
```

How to pass the id which I get through "$_GET['id'] to controller resetAction function.Now I am getting O as its value?

Comment: $_GET isn't something you should ever be using within ZF2. And the way you update the password is horribly dangerous, therefore I advise you to check out about password security as well. The way things are right now, you are endangered to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the $_GET directly when using ZF2, you can do this in your `changePasswordAction`:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'id' => $id));
```

and then in your `changepassword.phtml` you can directly use this variable as `$this->id`

Another note on your code: you should be careful with such SQL which may be vulnerable to SQL Injection...

Comment: But how this id will be fetched in resetAction() so that I can fire query to reset password

Comment: You have to replace `$_GET['id']` in your line `$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,array('controller'=>'Forgot', 'action' =>'reset','id'=>$this->id)));` and then `$id=$this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);` will work fine...

Comment: still I am getting value of id as 0